# Customize ODOO 15 POS Receipt

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, point-of-sale, receipt

I'm trying to add some new fields that are stored in the pos.order into the POS receipt. However, I don't know how to add them to the JS, I've tried to create a model, followed several tutos but I could not resolve my issue. My main issue is that in those tutorials, they use already defined methods to add their object in the receipt. For example, they add a field in the res.partner then use get_client(). When I use get_order() I can't get my new field.

Any help ?

Could you help with this ?